# Using ComTypes.ITypeInfo.CreateInstance object's information to expose interfaces within a coclass

Tags: c#, .net, com

I'm working with some unmanaged type libraries and reference files in a C# (.NET) application to get information out of them, such as the interfaces, functions, enums, etc, that they contain. I currently have an object of type ComTypes.ITypeInfo that represents a coclass. I've already written some code to get the coclass's name, however what I really want is a list of all the names of the interfaces contained within that coclass. I couldn't find any "easy-access" properties in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes namespace, so to meet this end, I'm currently using [ITypeInfo.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypeinfo.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx). From my understanding, by doing this I can get out a COM object of type Object and then get the desired information from it (I'm a beginner at COM so feel free to point out where I'm incorrect).

I can get all the way to where I've successfully made the call on a coclass and got out an Object of type "object {System.__ComObject}", however I'm not sure where to go from there. How can I use this coclass COM object to obtain the names of the interfaces it contains? Here's the code I'm using to get the coclass COM object:

```
//Assume the ti object below is already initialized as an object of TYPEKIND.TKIND_COCLASS
ComTypes.ITypeInfo ti;
if(//Condition where we know ti is a coclass)
{
   try
   {
      int href;
      Object obj;
      for (var i = 0; i < tiTypeAttr.cImplTypes; i++)
      {
         ti.GetRefTypeOfImplType(i, out href);
         ComTypes.ITypeInfo newTi;
         ti.GetRefTypeInfo(href, out newTi);
         if (newTi != null)
         {
            IntPtr attrP;
            ComTypes.TYPEATTR attr;
            newTi.GetTypeAttr(out attrP);
            attr = (ComTypes.TYPEATTR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(attrP, typeof(ComTypes.TYPEATTR));
            if (attr.typekind == ComTypes.TYPEKIND.TKIND_INTERFACE || attr.typekind == ComTypes.TYPEKIND.TKIND_DISPATCH)
            {
               Guid iid = attr.guid;
               ti.CreateInstance(null, iid, out obj);
               //STUCK HERE: Do stuff with obj to acquire the interface names within it
               newTi.ReleaseTypeAttr(attrP);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {Console.WriteLine(e);}
}
```

Is there a way to use that Object obj to get the info I'm looking for? Or is there an easier way/a way at all? Thank you!

Comment: You need to obtain the fields or you already know the names? If you already know the names you can use `dynamic`

Comment: @codroipo All I know is the name of the coclass and have an object of type ITypeInfo that represents it. I have no idea what is inside of the coclass. What I meant by saying names instead of fields is that I don't need to use any of the fields, I just want a string representing what they're called. So if I had a coclass `foo` which had two interfaces `IBar` and `IExample`, I just want the strings IBar and IExample; I don't care what they contain/do.

Comment: You call `GetTypeAttr`, for `TYPEATTR::cImplTypes`. Then you call `GetRefTypeOfImplType` and `GetRefTypeInfo` in a loop from 0 through `cImplTypes-1`. `GetRefTypeInfo` gives you `ITypeInfo` representing an interface.

Comment: My knowledge of this is pretty basic, but have you tried using `Marshal.GetTypeForITypeInfo` to return a .Net `Type` object and then use `Type.GetInterfaces` to get the names you seek?